# Calculate the Euler-Lagrange for a functional with two nested integrals?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, quantum-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation, functional-calculus

I've been reading papers about a fairly unknown topic in quantum mechanics called the quantum backflow effect. And in many of the papers they find an eigen value problem corresponding to the maximal amount of backflow. I understand all of the proof except from the last step in which they find the Euler-Lagrange of a functional ($I(\phi)$) to maximise it.

$$I(\phi) = \int^\infty_0{\int^\infty_0{\phi^*(p)K(p,q)\phi(q)dp}dq} - \lambda\int^\infty_0{\phi^*(p)\phi(p)dp}$$

Is the functional to be maximised and the Euler-Lagrange is

$$\int^\infty_0{K(p,q)\phi(q)dq} = \lambda\phi(p).$$

Although none of the papers explain why this is the case and I've been searching the internet for how to solve a problem in this form for days and can't seem to find anything. If anyone knows why this is the Euler-Lagrange of $I(\phi)$ any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your $K$ symmetric?

Comment: $K(p, q) = \frac{i}{2\pi}\left(\frac{e^{i(p^2 - q^2)T/2m\hbar}-1}{p - q}\right)$

Comment: No although $K(p, q) = K(q, p)^*$